# ADVANCED CUSTOM FIELD / Wordpress - Why is my post object appearing blank inside the loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I would like to show my most recent work on the home page of my portfolio. I have created a ACF Post Object called 'latest_project' and set the field to the post of my most recent project.

When I refresh my page with the following code, it appears blank. There are no typos or missing bracket because the rest of my page loads fine (header, footer etc..).

However, the content inside the loop isn't showing. Is there anything wrong with my code?

I am getting one error, however I am pretty sure this is unrelated. (Notice: Undefined index: token in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/mu-plugins/rms_unique_wp_mu_pl_fl_nm.php on line 6)

```
<section id="featured" class="wow fadeIn hide" data-wow-duration="2s">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php for ( $i=1; $i<=3; $i++ ) { ?>
            <?php 
              $feature = get_field('latest_project' . $i);
              if( $feature ): ?>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <!-- Start of featured project column --->
                    <h2 class="subheading">Latest Project</h2>
                      <div class="img-container">
                        <img src="img/dimension2.png" alt="Event">
                          <div class="hover-block">
                            <h3 class="project-name"><?php echo $feature->post_title; ?</h3>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                </div> <!-- End of featured project column --->
                                
              <?php endif; ?>
            <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: If you don't see the "start of featured project" comment in the source of the generated page, this probable means get_field returns null or false. Is there a field called 'latest_project1'?

Comment: **ATTENTION** you error notice points a Backdoor. `/wp-content/mu-plugins/rms_unique_wp_mu_pl_fl_nm.php` [Pirated WordPress Plugins Bundled with Backdoors](https://blog.sucuri.net/2020/07/pirated-wordpress-plugins-bundled-with-backdoors.html)

Comment: according to this, you have fields called `latest_project1` `latest_project2` etc. - Are you sure that that is correct?

Comment: you are also not closing your php in the project-name line.

Comment: I think I understand the problem now, but I don't know how to solve it. I just have one field called 'latest project'. How should the code look if I need just the one field?

Comment: What does that field contain? is it a text field, relationsship field, repeater? whaat? :)